# How to change limit of characters in SEO plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress with "All In One SEO" plugin (not Pro version). I need to write quite long meta tags, but there's a limit: 60 characters. How to increase it? Cannot find this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this code:

```
function custom_ai1seo_meta_length($length) {
    return 250; // number of chars
}

add_filter('aioseop_title_length', 'custom_ai1seo_meta_length');
add_filter('aioseop_description_length', 'custom_ai1seo_meta_length');
```

Answer (score 0):

The character limit on these meta tags comes from search engine limitations, not the plugins.

Comment: What if I use some other plug in? Will the result be the same?

Answer (score -1):

You should then try Yoast SEO or any other plugin if you are not getting any solution in all in one.

Comment: Unfortunately Yoast cannot be installed on this version of Wordpress.